# tsql for xml, complex xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm trying to fetch some xml and looks like my structure doesn't fit any learning example I checked, I can't do select ... from xml.nodes.   How I can get all values for measure id (aba,cbp) and  value den for ABA (=777).
[image]

This was my first approach and it doesn't work

```
    SELECT xmldata
 , n0.b.value('(@type)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as  c1   --<  'GGM'
 , n.b.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as  m1   --<  ABA
 , n.b.value('(@id)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as  m2   --<  CBP
 FROM z
 CROSS APPLY z.xmldata.nodes('//submission/component/audit/data/measures/measure') AS n(b)
 CROSS APPLY z.xmldata.nodes('//submission/component') AS n0(b)
```

below is test load:

```
   DECLARE @MyXML XML;
    SET @MyXML =
     ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <submission vendor-id="9999" guid="1234-5678-4578-4784" xmlns="http://www.ncqa.org/ns/2006/idss/hedis">
    <metadata>
        <version>41</version>
        <timestamp/>
        <sub-id>1434588</sub-id>
        <org-id/>
        <org-name/>
        <product-line>NC15</product-line>
        <reporting-product/>
        <special-project/>
        <special-area/>
        <hcfa-contract/>
        <hcfa-area/>
        <year-end-date>12/31/2016</year-end-date>
        <audit>true</audit>
    </metadata>
    <component type="GGM">
    <audit>
       <measures>
            <measure id="aba">
            <reported>true</reported>
            <benefit>true</benefit>
            <data-elements>
            <data-element id="rate">
            <audit-designation>false</audit-designation>
            <comment/>
            </data-element>
            </data-elements>
            </measure>
            <measure id="cbp">
            <reported>true</reported>
            <benefit>true</benefit>
            <data-elements>
            <data-element id="rate">
            <audit-designation>false</audit-designation>
            <comment/>
            </data-element>
            </data-elements>
            </measure>

       </measures>

       <data>
       <measures>
            <measure id="aba" measure-version-id="44444-222222-33333">
            <data-elements>
                <data-element id="den">
                <value>777</value>
                </data-element>
                <data-element id="elignu">
                <value>48</value>
                </data-element>
                <data-element id="eligpop">
                <value>777</value>
                </data-element>
            </data-elements>

        </measure>
        <measure id="cbp" measure-version-id="11111-222222-33333">
            <data-elements>
            <data-element id="admexc">
            <value>0</value>
            </data-element>
            <data-element id="collmeth">
            <value>H</value>
            </data-element>
            <data-element id="dentot">
            <value>355</value>
            </data-element>
            <data-element id="eligtot">
            <value>123</value>
            </data-element>
            <data-element id="empexc">
            <value>0</value>
            </data-element>


            </data-elements>
            </measure>  

       </measures>

       </data>
       </audit>
    </component> 
    </submission>')

     SELECT @MyXML as xmldata into z;
```

Comment: Thx for the *test load*! +1 from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you show:

> Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only
>   be invoked on columns of type xml.

... points to a table's column which contains an XML, but is not typed correctly. You will have to cast this first (e.g. `CAST StringXML AS XML`). If possible, you should **store** the value as XML. This is **much faster!!**

**About reading your XML**

In your top node `<submission>` there is a default namespace `xmlns="something"`. When reading the XML you must either declare this namespace or you must use a namespace wildcard (`*:`). The general advise is: Be as specific as possible!

Try it like this:

Reading one value out of `<metadata>`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.ncqa.org/ns/2006/idss/hedis')
SELECT @MyXML.value(N'(/submission/metadata/version)[1]',N'int') AS metadata_version;
```

--The query you probably need

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.ncqa.org/ns/2006/idss/hedis')
SELECT m.value(N'@id',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,m.value(N'(data-elements/data-element[@id="den"]/value/text())[1]',N'int')
FROM @MyXML.nodes(N'/submission/component/audit/data/measures/measure') AS A(m);
```

The same for lazy people (not recommended)

```
SELECT m.value(N'@id',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,m.value(N'(*:data-elements/*:data-element[@id="den"]/*:value/text())[1]',N'int')
FROM @MyXML.nodes(N'//*:data//*:measure') AS A(m);
```